# Fast Fourier Transform of subset of vibration dataset

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing, fft, vibration

I am new at signal processing. I am trying to compute and plot FFT of a given dataset. The dataset corresponds to vibration signals captured using accelerometer. Dataset contains amplitude in x, y and z direction along with time.

The problem that I am facing is when I try to take a subset of the data, the FFT gives a straight line, I cannot see the frequencies and amplitude in those. Below is the code that I am using:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.fftpack import fft
from scipy import signal
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import time

#Prompt user for file
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Two Column CSV","*.csv")])
print(file_path)
title = input("Enter Experiment Name: ")

#Load Data (assumes two column array
tic = time.process_time()
x, y, z, t = np.genfromtxt(file_path,delimiter=',', unpack=True)
print(t)
toc = time.process_time()
print("Load Time:",toc-tic)

#Determine variables
N = np.int(np.prod(t.shape))#length of the array
Fs = 1/((t[1]-t[0])/10**9)  #sample rate (Hz)
total_duration = (t[-1] - t[0])/10**9
T = 1/Fs
t_sec = [(t[i+1] - t[0])/10**9 for i in range(0,len(t)-1)]
print('Total Duration: ', total_duration)
print("# Samples:",N)
print('Sampling rate: ',Fs)

tic = time.process_time()
fig_fft, host_fft = plt.subplots()
fig_fft.set_size_inches(16,9)
plt.figure(3)  
xf = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0/(2.0*T), N//2)
yf = fft(x)
plt.plot(xf, 2.0/N * np.abs(yf[0:np.int(N/2)]))
plt.grid()
plt.xlabel('Frequency (Hz)', fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel('Acc (m/$sec^2$)', fontsize=14)
plt.title('FFT (X)- ' + title, fontsize=18)
plt.savefig('FFT (X) {}'.format(title), dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

[here is the link to main dataset](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zz7rjpkbs8vn37t/top_aumpole_25092021.csv?dl=0)

[here is the link to 10sec data extracted from above dataset](https://www.dropbox.com/s/276xj0kefc7znbl/top_280_290.csv?dl=0)

[image: Time series plot for subset]

[image]

please let me know how to fix this problem.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I frequently had this problem. The zeroth entry of the Fourier transform contains the integral (or the sum) of the signal. If your signal is not centered around zero, this entry will be always very large.

There are two easy ways to get around this: Either center the measured data around zero (but maybe you want to keep that information of the center for something else)

```
x = x - np.mean(x)
```

Alternatively, simply set the zeroth component to zero:

```
yf[0] = 0
```

A third way would be not to plot the zeroth entry of the array.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem.  The graphs are correct.  Neither one of them is a straight line, but the fact is your full data is nearly DC, and your subset data is much more so, so virtually all of the energy is in the first bin.  If you zoom in narrowly on the rest of the graph, you'll see that it's not straight.

[image]

**FOLLOWUP**

At @terri's suggestion, here is a plot of your 'x' data with the DC component removed (via `x -= x.mean()`).  Note that the amplitudes here are tiny in comparison to the original DC component.  That's why you don't see them in the plot.  They were all there, just very small values.  Your data is practically white noise.  There just aren't any strong frequency components.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply! but if we plot the time series of the subset we can see that most of the acceleration lies in 0.8-0.82 but here those accelerations are getting skipped/omitted. Please refer to the edit I have posted.

Comment: NOTHING IS BEING OMITTED.  Perhaps you are confused about what an FFT does.  In your "x" data, which is what you are plotting, the DC component is 0.49, and the other amplitudes are +/- 0.04.  It is not at all surprising that the DC component of the FFT swamps the other miniscule frequency components.